# Display a UIAlertView in NSObject Class

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, nsobject

I'm building a login system within my app that will be called several times. So instead of copying and pasting the code into several spots, I'm of course making an NSObject class so I can call the class when needed, instead.

The login system will display a UIAlertView, and when "OK" is tapped, the system will attempt to log in. I can call the class and the UIAlertView will show, but I cannot tell which buttons are tapped. Here is my code:

```
//Calling the login system

Login *login = [[Login alloc] init];
```

**Login.h**:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Login : NSObject <UIAlertViewDelegate> {

}

@end
```

**Login.m**:

```
#import "Login.h"

@implementation Login

+(void)initialize {

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Login" message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"OK", nil];

    [alert show];
    [alert release];

    NSLog(@"Testing");

}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex  {

    NSLog(@"Here");

    NSString *title = [alertView buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex];  

    if([title isEqualToString:@"OK"]) {

        NSLog(@"Tapped");

    }

}

@end
```

For now, before I put UITextFields in the view, I just want to get the app to know which button was tapped. `Testing` appears in the log, but neither `Here` nor `Tapped` appear. Thanks!

Comment: Don't override `+(void)initialize`!!!! `+initialize` is **much** different than `-init`! You need to make sure you're appropriately calling `super` as well. Furthermore, make sure you're following MVC guidelines. Usually model objects shouldn't display UI elements.

Comment: Jack Lawrence is right: who is self that it is a UIAlertView delegate? it's not even initialized, that's way it doesn't get called as a delegate.

Comment: You guys are right! I haven't done this before, so I changed +(void)initialize to -(id)init and it worked. Jack Lawrence: write your comment as an answer so I can mark you right.

Comment: +1 , if SO had +2 option i would have.. your example saved my time for searching how to override ok action :) thanks @jack Humphrises

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your alert view should not be called by the class method +(void)initialize but by the instance -(id)init method that's why your instance doesn't get the notifications.

the class method "+(void)initialize" is called when the class first load.

the instance method "-(id)init" has its name beginning by init, and is called when you create (instantiate) your object.

```
-(id)init {

    //alert view

    self = [super init];

    return self;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. For people reading this answer: change +(void)initialize to -(id)init.

Comment: improved according to @JackLawrence comment

Answer (score 0):

Just

```
switch(buttonIndex){
    case 0:
        NSLog(@"Tapped First Button");
        break;
    case 1:
        break;
    default:
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use `self` in a class method you're referring to the class itself, rather than an instance of the class.  However, your delegate method is an instance method.  You probably want the caller to create a Login instance and have the instance create the alert, plus be its delegate.

Answer (score 0):

It's Simple :

Create a property for your NSObject class in your view controller class :

in h file :

@property (nonatomic , retain) LoginCheckNSObject *LoginCheckerObject;

in m file :

```
self.LoginCheckerObject=[[LoginCheckNSObject alloc] init];
[self.LoginCheckerObject setDelegate:self];
[self.LoginCheckerObject TrackNowLogin];
```

Comment: @ Jack Humphries  , add it in your view controller class . That's it